# How to solve this second order ODE not exclusively in terms of y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\left(x+\mathrm{e}^{2y}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=0
$$

Any help solving this ODE would be appreciated. I am confused due to a)the presence of both $x$ and $y$ terms and b) the $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$.

Thanks.

Comment: what have tried?

Comment: Maple can solve this equation this solution looks terrible

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(x+e^{2y})\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=0$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)+(x+e^{2y})\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=0$

$\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{dx}{dy}}\right)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+(x+e^{2y})\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3=0$

$-\dfrac{\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}}{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}+(x+e^{2y})\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=0$

$-\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}+(x+e^{2y})\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=0$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}-x-e^{2y}=0$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}-x=e^{2y}$

Now it is just a linear second-order ODE.